# Who is the giant in the final boss fight of God of War 4?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

Do we know who this giant is from the final boss fight in the 2018 game God of War 4?

[image: Giant]

I've searched the various God of War wikis but haven't found any mention of him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Thamur](http://godofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Thamur).

There are several references to him throughout the story, and he is part of the main quest line to get the chisel.

Mimir tells Kratos and Atreus of his origin, and demise, on their way to the corpse of Thamur. You can also see him on the map.

Comment: Killed with his own chisel by Thor. Re-animated using Vanir magic by Freya.

Comment: Aha, thanks :-) I revisited Thamur's corpse and I now see it's the same giant.